# Alt-Coin Wallet QT Project for Mac OS-X

Tags: qt, makefile, macos

I was told my QT Project file is a hot mess. I'm returning to C++ after many years of doing Java and I'm really new to QT. I would like someone familiar with QT Project files to give my code a once over and provide a critique with suggestions for improvement. I have to use `install_name_tool` to set `@rpath` after I build in QT Creator. That was not fun finding a solution there but that's when I was told my project file is a mess. I started modifying a file from another altcoin to be by own new coin. It seems that no one has kept up with the os-x builds, core or QT (GUI). Please do a code review of my project file.

```
# QT Project File
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = cybill-wallet
macx:TARGET = "cybill-wallet"
VERSION = 0.1.0
INCLUDEPATH += src src/json src/qt
DEFINES += QT_GUI BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE
CONFIG += no_include_pwd
CONFIG += thread
CONFIG += static
QT += core gui network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += widgets
}

# for boost > 1.37, add -mt to the boost libraries
# use: qmake BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=-mt
# for boost thread win32 with _win32 sufix
# use: BOOST_THREAD_LIB_SUFFIX=_win32-...
# when linking against a specific BerkelyDB version: BDB_LIB_SUFFIX=-4.8

# Dependency library locations can be customized using following settings 
# winbuild dependencies

win32 {
#    BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=-mgw49-mt-s-1_58
    BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/boost_1_58_0
    BOOST_LIB_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib
    BDB_INCLUDE_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix
    BDB_LIB_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix
    OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/openssl-1.0.2j/include
    OPENSSL_LIB_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/openssl-1.0.2j
    MINIUPNPC_INCLUDE_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/miniupnpc
    MINIUPNPC_LIB_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/miniupnpc
    QRENCODE_INCLUDE_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/qrencode-3.4.3
    QRENCODE_LIB_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/qrencode-3.4.3/.libs
    GMP_INCLUDE_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/gmp-6.0.0
    GMP_LIB_PATH=$$DEPSDIR/gmp-6.0.0/.libs
}

OBJECTS_DIR = build
MOC_DIR = build
UI_DIR = build

# use: qmake "RELEASE=1"
contains(RELEASE, 1) {
    # Mac: compile for maximum compatibility (10.5, 64-bit)
    macx:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -arch x86_64 -    isysroot $(xcode-select --print-path)/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk

    !windows:!macx {
        # Linux: static link
        LIBS += -Wl,-Bstatic
    }
}

!win32 {
# for extra security against potential buffer overflows: enable GCCs     Stack Smashing Protection
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= -fstack-protector-all --param ssp-buffer-size=1
QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -fstack-protector-all --param ssp-buffer-size=1
# We need to exclude this for Windows cross compile with MinGW 4.2.x, as     it will result in a non-working executable!
# This can be enabled for Windows, when we switch to MinGW >= 4.4.x.
}
# for extra security on Windows: enable ASLR and DEP via GCC linker     flags
#win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat -Wl,--large-    address-aware -static
win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat -static
win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

# use: qmake "USE_QRCODE=1"
# libqrencode (http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.en.html) must be     installed for support
contains(USE_QRCODE, 1) {
    message(Building with QRCode support)
    DEFINES += USE_QRCODE
    LIBS += -lqrencode
}

# use: qmake "USE_UPNP=1" ( enabled by default; default)
#  or: qmake "USE_UPNP=0" (disabled by default)
#  or: qmake "USE_UPNP=-" (not supported)
# miniupnpc (http://miniupnp.free.fr/files/) must be installed for     support
contains(USE_UPNP, -) {
    message(Building without UPNP support)
} else {
    message(Building with UPNP support)
    count(USE_UPNP, 0) {
        USE_UPNP=1
    }
    DEFINES += USE_UPNP=$$USE_UPNP STATICLIB
    INCLUDEPATH += $$MINIUPNPC_INCLUDE_PATH
    LIBS += $$join(MINIUPNPC_LIB_PATH,,-L,) -lminiupnpc
    win32:LIBS += -liphlpapi
}


# use: qmake "USE_DBUS=1"
contains(USE_DBUS, 1) {
    message(Building with DBUS (Freedesktop notifications) support)
    DEFINES += USE_DBUS
    QT += dbus
}

# use: qmake "USE_IPV6=1" ( enabled by default; default)
#  or: qmake "USE_IPV6=0" (disabled by default)
#  or: qmake "USE_IPV6=-" (not supported)
contains(USE_IPV6, -) {
    message(Building without IPv6 support)
} else {
    message(Building with IPv6 support)
    count(USE_IPV6, 0) {
        USE_IPV6=1
    }
    DEFINES += USE_IPV6=$$USE_IPV6
}

contains(BITCOIN_NEED_QT_PLUGINS, 1) {
    DEFINES += BITCOIN_NEED_QT_PLUGINS
    QTPLUGIN += qcncodecs qjpcodecs qtwcodecs qkrcodecs     qtaccessiblewidgets
}

INCLUDEPATH += src/leveldb/include src/leveldb/helpers
LIBS += $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a $$PWD/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a
SOURCES += src/txdb.cpp \
    src/qt/magi.cpp \
    src/qt/magiaddressvalidator.cpp \
    src/qt/magiamountfield.cpp \
    src/qt/magigui.cpp \
    src/qt/magistrings.cpp \
    src/qt/magiunits.cpp \
    src/magirpc.cpp \
    src/clientversion.cpp \
    src/qt/utilitydialog.cpp
!win32 {
    # we use QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE even without RELEASE=1 because we     use RELEASE to indicate linking preferences not -O preferences
    genleveldb.commands = cd $$PWD/src/leveldb && CC=$$QMAKE_CC     CXX=$$QMAKE_CXX $(MAKE) OPT=\"$$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE\"     libleveldb.a libmemenv.a
} else {
    # make an educated guess about what the ranlib command is called
    isEmpty(QMAKE_RANLIB) {
        QMAKE_RANLIB = $$replace(QMAKE_STRIP, strip, ranlib)
    }
    LIBS += -lshlwapi
    genleveldb.commands = cd $$PWD/src/leveldb && CC=$$QMAKE_CC     CXX=$$QMAKE_CXX TARGET_OS=OS_WINDOWS_CROSSCOMPILE $(MAKE)     OPT=\"$$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE\" libleveldb.a libmemenv.a     && $$QMAKE_RANLIB $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a && $$QMAKE_RANLIB     $$PWD/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a
}

genleveldb.target = $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a
genleveldb.depends = FORCE
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += genleveldb
# Gross ugly hack that depends on qmake internals, unfortunately there     is no other way to do it.
QMAKE_CLEAN += $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a; cd $$PWD/src/leveldb ;     $(MAKE) clean

# regenerate src/build.h
!windows|contains(USE_BUILD_INFO, 1) {
    genbuild.depends = FORCE
    genbuild.commands = cd $$PWD; /bin/sh share/genbuild.sh     $$OUT_PWD/build/build.h
    genbuild.target = $$OUT_PWD/build/build.h
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/build/build.h
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += genbuild
    DEFINES += HAVE_BUILD_INFO
}

# If we have an ARM device, we can't use SSE2 instructions, so don't try     to use them
QMAKE_XCPUARCH = $$QMAKE_HOST.arch
equals(QMAKE_XCPUARCH, armv7l) {
    message(Building without SSE2 support)
}
else:equals(QMAKE_XCPUARCH, armv6l) {
    message(Building without SSE2 support)
}
else {
    message(Building with SSE2 support)
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -msse2
    QMAKE_CFLAGS += -msse2
}
#endif

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall -Wextra -    Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstack-protector

# Input
DEPENDPATH += src src/json src/qt
HEADERS += \
    src/qt/transactiontablemodel.h \
    src/qt/addresstablemodel.h \
    src/qt/optionsdialog.h \
    src/qt/coincontroldialog.h \
    src/qt/coincontroltreewidget.h \
    src/qt/sendcoinsdialog.h \
    src/qt/addressbookpage.h \
    src/qt/signverifymessagedialog.h \
    src/qt/editaddressdialog.h \
    src/alert.h \
    src/addrman.h \
    src/base58.h \
    src/bignum.h \
    src/checkpoints.h \
    src/compat.h \
    src/coincontrol.h \
    src/sync.h \
    src/util.h \
    src/hash.h \
    src/uint256.h \
    src/kernel.h \
    src/scrypt_mine.h \
    src/pbkdf2.h \
    src/serialize.h \
    src/strlcpy.h \
    src/main.h \
    src/net.h \
    src/key.h \
    src/db.h \
    src/txdb.h \
    src/walletdb.h \
    src/script.h \
    src/init.h \
    src/mruset.h \
    src/magimath.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_writer_template.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_writer.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_value.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_utils.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_stream_reader.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_reader_template.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_reader.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_error_position.h \
    src/json/json_spirit.h \
    src/qt/clientmodel.h \
    src/qt/guiutil.h \
    src/qt/transactionrecord.h \
    src/qt/guiconstants.h \
    src/qt/optionsmodel.h \
    src/qt/monitoreddatamapper.h \
    src/qt/transactiondesc.h \
    src/qt/transactiondescdialog.h \
    src/qt/updatecheck.h \
    src/wallet.h \
    src/keystore.h \
    src/qt/transactionfilterproxy.h \
    src/qt/transactionview.h \
    src/qt/walletmodel.h \
    src/qt/overviewpage.h \
    src/qt/csvmodelwriter.h \
    src/crypter.h \
    src/qt/sendcoinsentry.h \
    src/qt/qvalidatedlineedit.h \
    src/qt/qvaluecombobox.h \
    src/qt/askpassphrasedialog.h \
    src/protocol.h \
    src/qt/notificator.h \
    src/qt/qtipcserver.h \
    src/allocators.h \
    src/ui_interface.h \
    src/qt/console.h \
    src/qt/rpcconsole.h \
    src/version.h \
    src/netbase.h \
    src/clientversion.h \
    src/hash_magi.h \
    src/hash/sph_types.h \
    src/hash/sph_keccak.h \
    src/hash/sph_haval.h \
    src/hash/sph_ripemd.h \
    src/hash/sph_sha2.h \
    src/hash/sph_tiger.h \
    src/hash/sph_whirlpool.h \
    src/qt/magiaddressvalidator.h \
    src/qt/magiamountfield.h \
    src/qt/magigui.h \
    src/qt/magiunits.h \
    src/magirpc.h \
    src/qt/utilitydialog.h

SOURCES += \
    src/qt/transactiontablemodel.cpp \
    src/qt/addresstablemodel.cpp \
    src/qt/optionsdialog.cpp \
    src/qt/sendcoinsdialog.cpp \
    src/qt/coincontroldialog.cpp \
    src/qt/coincontroltreewidget.cpp \
    src/qt/addressbookpage.cpp \
    src/qt/signverifymessagedialog.cpp \
    src/qt/editaddressdialog.cpp \
    src/alert.cpp \
    src/sync.cpp \
    src/util.cpp \
    src/hash.cpp \
    src/netbase.cpp \
    src/key.cpp \
    src/script.cpp \
    src/main.cpp \
    src/init.cpp \
    src/net.cpp \
    src/checkpoints.cpp \
    src/addrman.cpp \
    src/db.cpp \
    src/walletdb.cpp \
    src/magimath.cpp \
    src/qt/clientmodel.cpp \
    src/qt/guiutil.cpp \
    src/qt/transactionrecord.cpp \
    src/qt/optionsmodel.cpp \
    src/qt/monitoreddatamapper.cpp \
    src/qt/transactiondesc.cpp \
    src/qt/transactiondescdialog.cpp \
    src/qt/updatecheck.cpp \
    src/wallet.cpp \
    src/keystore.cpp \
    src/qt/transactionfilterproxy.cpp \
    src/qt/transactionview.cpp \
    src/qt/walletmodel.cpp \
    src/rpcdump.cpp \
    src/rpcnet.cpp \
    src/rpcmining.cpp \
    src/rpcwallet.cpp \
    src/rpcblockchain.cpp \
    src/rpcrawtransaction.cpp \
    src/qt/overviewpage.cpp \
    src/qt/csvmodelwriter.cpp \
    src/crypter.cpp \
    src/qt/sendcoinsentry.cpp \
    src/qt/qvalidatedlineedit.cpp \
    src/qt/qvaluecombobox.cpp \
    src/qt/askpassphrasedialog.cpp \
    src/protocol.cpp \
    src/qt/notificator.cpp \
    src/qt/qtipcserver.cpp \
    src/qt/console.cpp \
    src/qt/rpcconsole.cpp \
    src/noui.cpp \
    src/kernel.cpp \
    src/pbkdf2.cpp \
    src/hash/keccak.cpp \
    src/hash/haval.cpp \
    src/hash/ripemd.cpp \
    src/hash/sha2.cpp \
    src/hash/sha2big.cpp \
    src/hash/tiger.cpp \
    src/hash/whirlpool.cpp

RESOURCES += \
    src/qt/magi.qrc

FORMS += \
    src/qt/forms/coincontroldialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/sendcoinsdialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/addressbookpage.ui \
    src/qt/forms/signverifymessagedialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/editaddressdialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/transactiondescdialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/overviewpage.ui \
    src/qt/forms/sendcoinsentry.ui \
    src/qt/forms/askpassphrasedialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/rpcconsole.ui \
    src/qt/forms/optionsdialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/console.ui \
    src/qt/forms/helpmessagedialog.ui

contains(USE_QRCODE, 1) {
HEADERS += src/qt/qrcodedialog.h
SOURCES += src/qt/qrcodedialog.cpp
FORMS += src/qt/forms/qrcodedialog.ui
}
contains(BITCOIN_QT_TEST, 1) {
SOURCES += src/qt/test/test_main.cpp \
    src/qt/test/uritests.cpp
HEADERS += src/qt/test/uritests.h
DEPENDPATH += src/qt/test
QT += testlib
TARGET = m-wallet_test
DEFINES += BITCOIN_QT_TEST
}

CODECFORTR = UTF-8

# for lrelease/lupdate
# also add new translations to src/qt/magi.qrc under translations/
TRANSLATIONS = $$files(src/qt/locale/bitcoin_*.ts)

isEmpty(QMAKE_LRELEASE) {
    win32:QMAKE_LRELEASE = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\\lrelease.exe
    else:QMAKE_LRELEASE = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/lrelease
}
isEmpty(QM_DIR):QM_DIR = $$PWD/src/qt/locale
# automatically build translations, so they can be included in resource     file
TSQM.name = lrelease ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
TSQM.input = TRANSLATIONS
TSQM.output = $$QM_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.qm
TSQM.commands = $$QMAKE_LRELEASE ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -qm ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
TSQM.CONFIG = no_link
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += TSQM

# "Other files" to show in Qt Creator
OTHER_FILES += README.md \
    doc/*.rst \
    doc/*.txt doc/README \
    src/qt/res/magi-qt.rc \
    src/test/*.cpp \
    src/test/*.h \
    src/qt/test/*.cpp \
    src/qt/test/*.h

# platform specific defaults, if not overridden on command line
isEmpty(BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX) {
    macx:BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX = -mt
    windows:BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX = -mgw49-mt-s-1_58
}

isEmpty(BOOST_THREAD_LIB_SUFFIX) {
    BOOST_THREAD_LIB_SUFFIX = $$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX
}

isEmpty(BDB_LIB_PATH) {
    macx:BDB_LIB_PATH = /opt/local/lib/db48
}

isEmpty(BDB_LIB_SUFFIX) {
    macx:BDB_LIB_SUFFIX = -4.8
}

isEmpty(BDB_INCLUDE_PATH) {
    macx:BDB_INCLUDE_PATH = /opt/local/include/db48
}

isEmpty(BOOST_LIB_PATH) {
    macx:BOOST_LIB_PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.57/1.57.0/lib
}

isEmpty(BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH) {
    macx:BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH = /opt/local/include
}

windows:DEFINES += WIN32
windows:RC_FILE = src/qt/res/magi-qt.rc

windows:!contains(MINGW_THREAD_BUGFIX, 0) {
    # At least qmake's win32-g++-cross profile is missing the -lmingwthrd
    # thread-safety flag. GCC has -mthreads to enable this, but it doesn't
    # work with static linking. -lmingwthrd must come BEFORE -lmingw, so
    # it is prepended to QMAKE_LIBS_QT_ENTRY.
    # It can be turned off with MINGW_THREAD_BUGFIX=0, just in case it     causes
    # any problems on some untested qmake profile now or in the future.
    DEFINES += _MT
    QMAKE_LIBS_QT_ENTRY = -lmingwthrd $$QMAKE_LIBS_QT_ENTRY
}

!windows:!macx {
    DEFINES += LINUX
    LIBS += -lrt
}

############################################
# MAC OS-X Specific
############################################
macx:CFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++ -    rpath=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.11.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
macx:INCLUDEPATH +=  /usr/local/Cellar/miniupnpc/2.1/include     /usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.57/1.57.0/include /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/include /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2/include /usr/local/Cellar/leveldb/1.20_2/include /usr/local/Cellar/berkeley-    db@4/4.8.30/include
macx:HEADERS += src/qt/macdockiconhandler.h src/qt/macnotificationhandler.h
macx:OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += src/qt/macdockiconhandler.mm src/qt/macnotificationhandler.mm
macx:LIBS += -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices -framework AppKit -framework CoreServices
macx:DEFINES += MAC_OSX MSG_NOSIGNAL=0
macx:ICON = src/qt/res/icons/cybill.icns
macx:CONFIG += -std=c++11
macx:QMAKE_CFLAGS_THREAD += -pthread -stdlib=libc++
macx:QMAKE_LFLAGS_THREAD += -pthread
macx:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_THREAD += -pthread -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11
macx:MINIUPNPC_LIB_PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/miniupnpc/2.1/lib
macx:LIBS += $$join(MINIUPNPC_LIB_PATH,,-L,) -lminiupnpc
macx:GMP_LIB_PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2/lib
macx:LIBS += $$join(GMP_LIB_PATH,,-L,) -lgmp
macx:OPENSSL_LIB_PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/lib
macx:LIBS += $$join(OPENSSL_LIB_PATH,,-L,) -lssl
macx:BOOST_LIB_PATH = /usr/local/Cellar/boost@1.57/1.57.0/lib
macx:LIBS += $$join(BOOST_LIB_PATH,,-L,) -lboost_system-mt
macx:LIBS += $$join(BOOST_LIB_PATH,,-L,) -lboost_thread-mt

# Set libraries and includes at end, to use platform-defined defaults if not overridden
INCLUDEPATH += $$OPT_INCLUDE_PATH $$BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH     $$BDB_INCLUDE_PATH $$OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH $$QRENCODE_INCLUDE_PATH     $$GMP_INCLUDE_PATH
LIBS += $$join(OPT_LIB_PATH,,-L,) $$join(BOOST_LIB_PATH,,-L,)     $$join(BDB_LIB_PATH,,-L,) $$join(OPENSSL_LIB_PATH,,-L,)     $$join(QRENCODE_LIB_PATH,,-L,) $$join(GMP_LIB_PATH,,-L,)
LIBS += -lssl -lgmp -lcrypto -ldb_cxx$$BDB_LIB_SUFFIX
LIBS += $$OPT_LIBS
# -lgdi32 has to happen after -lcrypto (see  #681)
windows:LIBS += -lws2_32 -lshlwapi -lmswsock -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -    lgdi32
LIBS += -lboost_system$$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX -    lboost_filesystem$$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX -    lboost_program_options$$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX -    lboost_thread$$BOOST_THREAD_LIB_SUFFIX
windows:LIBS += -lboost_chrono$$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX

contains(RELEASE, 1) {
    !windows:!macx {
        # Linux: turn dynamic linking back on for c/c++ runtime     libraries
        LIBS += -Wl,-Bdynamic
    }
}

system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent $$TRANSLATIONS)
```

Comment: Since no one has attempted to do a code review, I'll do a quick review. The project file is messy, however it's because the focus has been to build the application for Mac OS-X. Also, the existing file was from another project and I've tried to update it to get it to work for OS-X 10.13 (latest version). I'll refactor the file as I migrate to the other platforms.